QGis CRITICAL Layer vlayer (virtual layer)
While export offline with QField sync I´m getting follow error:
CRITICAL Layer vlayer : Error while executing feature count request : Query preparation  error on SELECT Count(*),Min(MbrMinX("")),Min(MbrMinY("")),Max(MbrMaxX("")),Max(MbrMaxY("")) FROM : incomplete input

The virtual layer has a simple script and a relationship to a point layer. In some situation I can´t export to QField. The progress bar is running a few percent, than freeze. I must save my project with another filename an/or delete some features from point layer. QField sync and QGIS with newest release and updates.


